# Managed identity Azure

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

How i can implement managed identity (azure) to access to video indexer services in AZURE?
Now the access to video indexer is handled with accessToken. Thank for collaborating.

I try to understand the use of managed identity but is not clear for me.
I don't understand how it help us to access without to handle secrets.

Answer (score 1):

Video Indexer have both classic and ARM based paid accounts. Assuming you already using the ARM offering (recommended) you can follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-video-indexer/connect-classic-account-to-arm#after-connecting-to-arm-is-complete

There is an ARM API call that enables you, using MI, to get an access token.